# Block whatsapp channels

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger

My phone, a galaxy s20 fe, recently updated whatsapp bringing along with it 'whatsapp channels'. Is there a way to block or get rid of the new whatsapp channels update?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Since this is an official feature of WhatsApp, I don't think there's a way to block/get rid of it other than using a 3rd-party/modded WhatsApp app, unless they finally add that options. Using the older version may only borrow some time because WhatsApp usually forces a minimum version after a certain time.